# appendChild JS Dando erro

Tags: javascript, html

Boa noite, estou alimentando o meu html com o JS usando o Seguinte código:

```
function loja(){
    const divLoja = document.querySelector('.teste')
    const api = new XMLHttpRequest()
    api.open('GET', `http://localhost:3000/produtos/class/loja`, true);
    api.send()
    api.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4){
            const dados = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
            console.log(dados)
            dados.produtos.forEach((item) => {
                let div = document.createElement('section');
                let itemDiv = `
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
                        <!-- Card -->
                        <div class="card card-cascade narrower card-ecommerce">
                            <!-- Card image -->
                            <div class="view view-cascade overlay">
                                <img src="${item.imagem}" class="card-img-top" alt="cartão ${item.nome}">
                                <a>
                                    <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Card image -->
                            <!-- Card content -->
                            <div class="card-body card-body-cascade text-center pb-3">
                                <!-- Title -->
                                <h5 class="card-title mb-1">
                                    <strong>
                    <a value="${item.id_produto}" data-value="${item.id_produto}"  onclick="redirect(this)" style="color: rgb(0, 153, 255);">${item.nome}</a>
                    </strong>
                                </h5>
                            
                                <!-- Description -->
                                <p class="card-text">Cartão pre-pago ${item.nome}</p>
                                <!-- Card footer -->
                                <div class="card-footer px-1">
                                    <span class="float-left font-weight-bold">
                    <strong>R$${item.preco}</strong>
                    </span>
                                    <span class="float-right">
                    <a class="material-tooltip-main" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Ver detalhes">
                        <i value="${item.id_produto}" data-value="${item.id_produto}" onclick="redirect(this)" class="fas fa-eye grey-text ml-3"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a class="material-tooltip-main" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Adicionar ao carrinho">
                            <i value="${item.id_produto}" data-value="${item.id_produto}" onclick="cartAddtocart(this)" class="fas fa-shopping-cart text-danger ml-3"></i>
                    </a>
                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Card content -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- Card -->
                    </div>
                `
                div.innerHTML = itemDiv;
                divLoja.appendChild(div)
            });
        }
    }
}

loja()
```

Quando eu crio um elemento no caso do meu teste foi o section tudo fica o html fica bugado pois é como se o css não se aplicasse no local certo.
Porem eu so tenho que adicionar cada elemento a minha div principal usando o forEach e se eu não tivesse que criar um elemento para conseguir adicionar daria certo. Porem quando eu uso o appendChild passando como argumento a própria template string da o seguinte erro:

```
full.js:57 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at full.js:57
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.api.onreadystatechange (full.js:11)
```

Tem como eu adicionar direto na minha div sem ter que criar outra div para cada elemento?

Answer (score 0):

Desculpa incomodar mas acabei descobrindo uma solução kk

é so pegar o elemento que está sendo criado e substituir pela primeira div que esta na minha template string e assim adicionar normalmente ao html

```
let div = document.createElement('div');
div.classList.add('col-lg-3', 'col-md-6', 'mb-4')
let itemDiv = `
               
                        <!-- Card -->
                        <div   class="card card-cascade narrower card-ecommerce">
                            <!-- Card image -->
                            <div class="view view-cascade overlay">
                                <img src="${item.imagem}" class="card-img-top" alt="cartão ${item.nome}">
                                <a>
                                    <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Card image -->
                            <!-- Card content -->
                            <div class="card-body card-body-cascade text-center pb-3">
                                <!-- Title -->
                                <h5 class="card-title mb-1">
                                    <strong>
                    <a value="${item.id_produto}" data-value="${item.id_produto}"  onclick="redirect(this)" style="color: rgb(0, 153, 255);">${item.nome}</a>
                    </strong>
                                </h5>
                            
                                <!-- Description -->
                                <p class="card-text">Cartão pre-pago ${item.nome}</p>
                                <!-- Card footer -->
                                <div class="card-footer px-1">
                                    <span class="float-left font-weight-bold">
                    <strong>R$${item.preco}</strong>
                    </span>
                                    <span class="float-right">
                    <a class="material-tooltip-main" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Ver detalhes">
                        <i value="${item.id_produto}" data-value="${item.id_produto}" onclick="redirect(this)" class="fas fa-eye grey-text ml-3"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a class="material-tooltip-main" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Adicionar ao carrinho">
                            <i value="${item.id_produto}" data-value="${item.id_produto}" onclick="cartAddtocart(this)" class="fas fa-shopping-cart text-danger ml-3"></i>
                    </a>
                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Card content -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- Card -->
                    
 `
div.innerHTML = itemDiv
divLoja.appendChild(div)
```